# Can't iterate and create a list from Django filter Query

Tags: python, django

In my project I have a Transaction model with a one to many relationship with the Coin model. Each transaction has a buy_price and unit_number (number of units). With the nested for loop in `views.py` below I am expecting to generate a list of multiple buy_prices within each coin dictionary.

The query on it's own (with the coin name hardcoded) outputs the multiple buy_prices data I am expecting - which is indeed what is in the database. But once I put all the code together, all I am ever getting is just one buy_price for each coin with - `print(coin_list)` What am I doing wrong?

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from .models import Coin, Transaction
from decimal import Decimal

def index(request):   
    coin_list = []
    coins = Coin.objects.all()

url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/{}?localization=false&tickers=false&market_data=true&community_data=false&developer_data=false&sparkline=false'

for coin in coins:
    db_coin_name = coin.name
    coin_data = requests.get(url.format(db_coin_name)).json()   

    api_current_price = Decimal(coin_data['market_data']['current_price']['eur'])           

    coin_dict = {
        'official_name': coin_data['name'],
        'symbol': coin_data['symbol'],
        'image': coin_data['image']['large'],            
    }

    transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(coin__name=f"{db_coin_name}")

    for t in transactions:
        buy_prices = []
        buy_prices.append(t.buy_price)

        print(buy_prices)


        coin_dict['transactions'] = {
            'buy_prices': buy_prices                                             
        }

    coin_list.append(coin_dict)

print(coin_list)
context = {'data': coin_list}
return render(request, 'cryptodashboard/index.html', context)
```

**Terminal output from `print(buy_prices)` - the first two belong to zcash and the second two belong to stellar**

```
[Decimal('10')]
[Decimal('5')]
[Decimal('0.189442')]
[Decimal('0.170867')]
```

**Terminal output from `print(coin_list)`**

```
[
   {
      'official_name':'Zcash',
      'symbol':'zec',
      'image':'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/486/large/circle-zcash-color.png?1534468310',
      'transactions':{
         'buy_prices':[
            Decimal('5')
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      'official_name':'Stellar',
      'symbol':'xlm',
      'image':'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/100/large/stellar_lumens.png?1510040249',
      'transactions':{
         'buy_prices':[
            Decimal('0.170867')
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

P.S Let me know if I need to provide any other code snippets. Been struggling with this for a while, so any help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
for t in transactions:
    buy_prices = []  # <-- here
    buy_prices.append(t.buy_price)

    print(buy_prices)


    coin_dict['transactions'] = {
        'buy_prices': buy_prices                                             
    }
```

You are making a new list each time you start a new iteration in transaction.

So maybe you can do it like this:

```
buy_prices = []
for t in transactions:
    buy_prices.append(t.buy_price)  
    coin_dict['transactions'] = {
        'buy_prices': buy_prices                                             
    }
```

Even better:

```
coin_dict['transactions'] = { 'buy_prices': list(transactions.values_list('buy_prices', flat=True))}

# No need for Transaction for loop
```

Comment: thanks so much, both solutions work perfectly! Quick question, in the template it is ok to also use a for loop to iterate over the flat transaction list?

Comment: Yes, of course. by using `list` has converted it into a list. I was under the impression that you are using it as JSON response.IMHO, if you are going to use it in template, then you can simply pass the `transaction` queryset, and iterate it there.( no need to use `buy_prices` list).